# Codeigniter session recreated on each page

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, cookies

I've created a site using CodeIgniter and its build in session class. I've uploaded it to a Plesk server, which has given me a demo url of: https://1.2.3.4:8443/sitepreview/http/mysite.com (not actual url, different ip and folder).

A new session is being created on each page view - I can tell because session data isn't kept between pages, and each time a new page is accessed, the session table get a row added to it.

The session is kept correctly locally, where the cookie config is as follows:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']    = "/";
```

I'm guessing the issue is with the cookie - I've used firebug to check, it appears the cookie IS getting sent to the server, but the server is responing with a replacement cookie.

I've tried various settings with the live config, but not managed to get anything to work. The variation I think should work correctly is

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "1.2.3.4:8443";
$config['cookie_path']    = "/sitepreview/http/mysite.com";
```

but it isn't!

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit more googling, I've found that its actually the Plesk site preview thats causing the issue - its not passing cookie data it recieves to the page.

http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=54222

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an issue with cookies.  I'd take a look at the documentation and double check that everything is setup correctly.  Make sure your using the correct drivers too.

Comment: You might find what your looking for here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html